# Virtual Directory to navigate to http://localhost/MyWebsite instead of http://localhost:8080

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7, localhost

I have deployed an ASP.NET MVC 4 application to a new site I have created in IIS 7.5, which I have bound to port 8080. I can reach it by navigating to http://localhost:8080, but I want to reach it via http://localhost/MyWebsite.

I have added a Virtual Directory under my website, which points to "`C:\inetput\wwwroot\MyWebsite\`". However, when I navigate to http://localhost/MyWebsite, I am presented with a configuration error:

> "It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS."

Here is what my IIS hierarchy looks like (this is a demo since I have no internet access on the server I am working on).

[image]

I have two questions:

1. Why am I getting this error?
2. Is this the best way to go about achieving what I want? It seems messy to have the list of files and folders underneath the website and then again underneath the Virtual Directory. If there is better practice then please tell!

Comment: Make MyWebsite folder an application (right click, convert to application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual Directories cannot execute scripts, reason why you are getting that error. You need to make your MyWebsite folder an Application. Also, you don't necessarily **have to** create a separate website for your website, you can use the Default Web Site and create an application MyWebsite in there (it might be less confusing maybe?).