# IIS VirtualDirectories, and accessing their contents from a ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, filesystems, virtual-directory

With Chromium no longer allowing links to local files I am attempting to test a couple of solutions to allow users to open PDF's on a local Network Share without having to download them first (the current work around).

I tested a pure JavaScript solution and that one worked great.

However I am trying use a Virtual Directory in IIS that points to a Network share with the files the user(s) can access.

When testing and trying to navigate to the file I have saved I get a "cannot find path error"
[image]

I created a test application and published it on my local machine.


**Below** is the screenshot of the Virtual Directory I created.
[image]

**Below** is the code I use to try and open the file.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult OpenPDF()
        {

            string directory = "./pdf";
            string file = "/light.pdf";
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(directory + file);

            return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf");
        }
```

I assumed that the virtual directory would be in the root directory. I tried to find some examples of a Virtual Directory being accessed in code, and I haven't found one.

**Resources I accessed:** 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory


[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/create-virtual-directory-folder-remote-computer#:~:text=In%20the%20Internet%20Information%20Services,and%20then%20click%20Virtual%20Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/create-virtual-directory-folder-remote-computer#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Internet%20Information%20Services,and%20then%20click%20Virtual%20Directory).


[Virtual Directory to navigate to http://localhost/MyWebsite instead of http://localhost:8080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437598/virtual-directory-to-navigate-to-http-localhost-mywebsite-instead-of-http-lo)


[Different between ./ , ../ , ../../ , ~/ on file path(URL) in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272954/different-between-on-file-pathurl-in-asp-net)


https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/francissvk/create-virtual-directory-in-iis/

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you return a `new VirtualFileResult("pdf/light.pdf", ""application/pdf");` because [*A FileResult that on execution writes the file specified using a virtual path to the response using mechanisms provided by the host.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.virtualfileresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Sorry I ma not using ASPNET core

Comment: Okay, do `Server.MapPath("~/pdf/light.pdf")` to get the right folder.

Comment: Server.MapPath worked. Now access is denied which is fine. Thats closer than I was before

Comment: You need to run the apppool under an network account so that you can grant it access to the network share.

Comment: Worked Rene! Thanks!. Wouldn't happen to know how to send the File() object to a newtab off hand would you?

Comment: You can't from the server but you can try adding a target="_blank" on the  link in the html. Not all browsers are happy to honor that.

Comment: Write an answer and I'll accept it Rene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core you can return an [VirtualFileResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.virtualfileresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

> A FileResult that on execution writes the file specified using a virtual path to the response using mechanisms provided by the host.

Or you can do a [`Server.MapPath("~/pdf/light.pdf")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8) to get the virtual path.

> Returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path.

In your example code you would use it as such:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OpenPDF()
{

    string directory = "/pdf"; // notice I removed the . 
    string file = "/light.pdf";
    var filepath = Server.MapPath("~" + directory + file);
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

    return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf");
}
```

Keep in mind that if for access to a network share your Application Pool needs to run under an identity that has access to said network share.

For a download of a file in a new tab try `<a href="/file.pdf" target="_blank">file</a>` in your client side html.